# Grant read only IAM Permission to ec2 resources based on Tag using custom policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I was trying to create an IAM policy with read only access to machines with certain tag and grant EC2 instance connect for those machines only.

I tried this. but not working.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2-instance-connect:SendSSHPublicKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:7352673452763:dedicated-host/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/Project": "TestProject"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:015107134915:dedicated-host/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/Project": "TestProject"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I couldn't see any machines when permissions are given. can someone help me with these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resource types supported by `ec2-instance-connect` permission are of

> arn:${Partition}:ec2:${Region}:${Account}:instance/${InstanceId}

and `ec2:Describe*` applies to all resources.

[Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon EC2 Instance Connect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2instanceconnect.html)

[Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon EC2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonec2.html)

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2-instance-connect:SendSSHPublicKey"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:7352673452763:instance/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/Project": "TestProject"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```